# How to get max column with non-zero value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
           2017      2018      2012  2015  2014  2016
11647  0.044795  0.000000  0.000000   0.0   0.0   0.0
16389  0.089801  0.044900  0.000000   0.0   0.0   0.0
16404  0.014323  0.000000  0.000000   0.0   0.04   0.0
16407  0.052479  0.010442  0.009277   0.0   0.0   0.0
16409  0.000000  0.000000  0.004883   0.0   0.0   5.0
```

Note that columns are not sorted.
For each row, I need to get the latest year with non-zero value.
So the expected result is:

```
11647    2017
16389    2018
16404    2017
16407    2018
16409    2016
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `idxmax` in a sorted-column df

```
df[sorted(df.columns, reverse=True)].ne(0).idxmax(1)

11647    2017
16389    2018
16404    2017
16407    2018
16409    2016
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is 5.3 times faster than mine (with `apply`).

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack` with `max`

```
df[df.ne(0)].stack().reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].max(level=0)
Out[386]: 
11647    2017
16389    2018
16404    2017
16407    2018
16409    2016
Name: level_1, dtype: int64
```

Just update

```
df.ne(0).mul(df.columns).max(1)
Out[423]: 
11647    2017.0
16389    2018.0
16404    2017.0
16407    2018.0
16409    2016.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is 3.1 times faster than mine (with `apply`), but the answer I've accepted is even faster.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov would you like try my update ? if the speed is matter , I think this one should be even faster  then idxmax

Comment: I'd glad to try, but it doesn't seem to work for me. `mul` operation raises `*** ValueError: cannot evaluate a numeric op with unequal lengths`. Why is that?

Comment: The shape of `df.ne(0)` is `(56, 6)` and `df.columns` is a list of 6 elements.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov try out with your example and compare with your original df , I think the dataframe is different

Comment: I just double checked with the original df. Your first solution works fine, but the second one doesn't. Can you post the full code (with df creation) to prove it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[row > 0].index.max(), axis=1)
```

gives the expected result.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking and answering your own questions

Comment: never said there was something wrong, just caught my attention that you already knew the answer

Comment: But also I think there should be a better way of doing this than `lambda`, having a go now but not sure I'm gonna get anywhere

Comment: @Yuca If you believe you're answering something that hasn't been covered in SO somewhere else then it's fair to initiate the process like that. The OP has not accepted their answer, so you could also read it as "I found a problem I don't think is answered on SO. This is how I solved it. I invite your attempts"

Comment: Thank you roganjosh. I think this question showcases why self-answering is fine. I was facing a problem that I hadn't found an answer to, then I came up with an answer and I wanted to share it with others. And then I got 2 more answers that are 3x and 5x faster than my original solution. This is the power of StackOverflow :) @Yuca

Comment: Agree @DennisGolomazov, glad we had this convo